# I am trying to run the onEdit function for three separate tabs but receiving TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, typeerror, user-defined-functions

I am trying to run the onEdit function for three separate tabs but receiving 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. The first function onEdit(e) runs properly by itself but not with the other two functions.

```
 function onEdit(e) { 
      if (e.value === 'COMPLETED FAB') {
        var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
        if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Fabrication') {                     
          logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Fabrication Completed');    
          var row = e.range.getRow(); 
          var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
          var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()); 
          range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
          sheet.deleteRow(row);
        }
      }
    }


    function onEdit(event) { 
      if (event.value === 'FINISHED') {
        var sheet1 = event.range.getSheet();
        if (sheet1.getSheetName() == 'Service') {                     
          logSheet1 = event.source.getSheetByName('Service Completed');  
          var row1 = event.range.getRow(); 
          var lastRow1 = logSheet1.getLastRow();
          var range1 = sheet1.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()); 
          range1.copyTo(logSheet1.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
          sheet1.deleteRow(row);
        }
      }
    }

    function onEdit(event2) { 
      if (event2.value === 'COMPLETED SURVEYS') {
        var sheet2 = event2.range.getSheet();
        if (sheet2.getSheetName() == 'Survey') {               
          logSheet2 = event2.source.getSheetByName('Fabrication');    
          var row2 = event2.range.getRow(); 
          var lastRow2 = logSheet2.getLastRow();
          var range2 = sheet2.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()); 
          range2.copyTo(logSheet2.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
          sheet2.deleteRow(row);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Before I spent any time on that, I'd consolidate these 3 functions into just one since they all do the same thing except for the strings that they work with, which could be determined at the top of the combined function with decision making logic. After that, this error likely won't even exist.

Comment: You may be missing the target: `if (e.target.value === 'COMPLETED FAB')`

Answer (score 1):

You should have only one `onEdit(e)` function and use if/else if statements to provide different functionalities for different event values.

```
function onEdit(e) {
      if (e.value === 'COMPLETED FAB') {
        // Rest of the code
      }
      else if (e.value === 'FINISHED') {
        // Rest of the code
      }
      else if (e.value === 'COMPLETED SURVEYS') {
        // Rest of the code
      }
}
```

Comment: This worked! However, I added two more else if statements and the two new else if functions wont work...

Comment: @Nick can you share your code of the other two if statements?

Comment: See above updated code where the else if statements works up until the last 3 else if statements that I added.

Answer (score 1):

One of the core principles of programming is DRY (Don't repeat yourself). You have three functions that only differ in the string values that are used, which means that they can all be combined into one function quite easily. Since you said that the first function runs no problem, it is likely that combining them would eliminate your error and create better code.

In the example code below, note that the lines that don't change are outside of the `if/then` statement.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  // Set strings and corresponding values
  let values = ["COMPLETED FAB","FINISHED","COMPLETED SURVEYS"];
  let states = ["Fabrication Completed", "Service Completed", "Fabrication"];

  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();

  if (e.value === values[0]) {
    if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Fabrication') {                     
      logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(sates[0]);    
    }
  } else if (e.value === values[1]) {
    if (sheet1.getSheetName() == 'Service') {                     
      logSheet1 = e.source.getSheetByName(states[1]);
    }  
  } else if (e.value === values[2]) {
    if (sheet2.getSheetName() == 'Survey') {               
      logSheet2 = e.source.getSheetByName(states[2]);    
    }
  } else {
    // No valid input
    return false;
  }

  var row = e.range.getRow(); 
  var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()); 
  range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
  sheet.deleteRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this did not work. I received an error on line 6.var sheet = e.range.getSheet();

Comment: @Nick That is a different problem and doesn't indicate that my approach doesn't work. Now you have to track down that error. What exactly was the message that was produced?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 6, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: So `e` is a reference to the `event` object. The error indicates that `range` is not a property of that JavaScript event. If you inspect the `event`, you can find out more about its type and other properties.